# Some flickering when scrolling down the answer list

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

There is some flickering when I try to scroll down the answer list. This happens only the first time when the listview elements get drawn first. After that no flicker.

Update - This issue got fixed in 0.1.26

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218046/152859) was reported now, has the bug returned for you too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem here, confirmed in both 0.1.23 and 0.1.24. My limited testing says it might be, if anything, more pronounced in 0.1.24 but I had already noticed it and was going to do a bug write up before the last update came over. The problem is very definitely still there in the current update.

This is very obvious and disconcerting. It happens specifically in the Answers tab of the question screen and it happens only on the first time scrolling down through the answer. The screen doesn't just flicker a little, it straight up flashes back and forth to white multiple times. It flashes enough that when it's done and you get the the bottom you wonder if it all got back together again and you scroll back up to see if everything is there. On the second and following scroll through either up or down, the display is smooth as normal.

Answer (score 8):

There are two issues at play here. One is a longstanding Android bug that causes (usually black) flickering with WebViews that have a transparent background and are drawn hardware accelerated, at least on some devices. This started happening in 0.1.24 where the backgrounds of questions and answers was made transparent. I have added a workaround for this issue, so this flickering will disappear in 0.1.26. It's broken again in 0.1.27 and fixed again in 0.1.28. WebViews and hardware acceleration are fun :\

The other issue (which isn't new) stems from the fact that WebViews are rendered asynchronously. When they first appear, they're empty, and shortly afterwards they change to their actual content. I'm investigating workarounds for this (I find it very annoying myself), but this is a much harder problem, so it may take a while to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. But does it have to be a WebView? (BTW, app became unresponsive and crashed when I was viewing your answer, I've sent an error report)

Comment: Given that questions and answers can (and often do) contain fairly rich content, a `WebView` is the logical thing to use. The alternative would be creating/using something that duplicates a lot of the HTML rendering functionality that `WebView` gives you for free, which for obvious reasons we'd rather avoid. It's unfortunate that `WebView` comes with so many issues.

Comment: I came back to edit my answer to note that some cases I was getting black instead of white flickering that persisted instead of going away after the first scroll. Looks like you have that one covered, so I won't bother to re-report it.

Comment: Is it possible that this has come back in 0.1.27, or that it wasn't fixed for meta sites? I didn't see this bug before, so I'm not sure what I'm seeing is the same thing. I'm seeing a lot of black flickering when scrolling through meta posts, for example here: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/lets-be-nice-to-each-other

Comment: For future reference: Discussion with @HodofHod continues at http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1517357#1517357

Comment: I have this bug again since about 1.0.10