# Scrolling bug in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, android-app, scrolling

In the Android app the text of the answers become garbled if I scroll the screen when viewing a question.

It is as if new text is being overwritten over the still existing old text. Other text, such as
comments, user names and the question itself scrolls fine.

I tried taking a screenshot but in the screenshot the area where the answer is appears as a solid black rectangle.

My phone is a Samsung GT-S7562 running Android 4.0.4

Have others experienced this?

Comment: Hmm... might be the return of [this old bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196008/152859)? Do you experience the same problem as he describes?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I not only see flickering but I have multiple copies of the answer text superimposed at different vertical positions so that nothing is readable.

Comment: Sounds like a bug... and if you scroll slowly, does it help?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No the speed does not seem to make a difference either way.

Comment: Having them superimposed makes me think this is a problem with the GPU rendering on your phone. The original galaxy S had a lot of these issues. I'll take a look to see what I can do.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Thanks

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi so this might explain other bugs reported in the last couple of days, isn't it? Maybe even the infamous [black box bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196968/152859)?

Comment: @Shadow they might be connected. I need to buy a Galaxy S and see.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi buy?! As a dev I'm pretty sure it's your employer's responsibility to buy you any device they plan to support. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was speaking more on the behalf of the company, I wouldn't be buying them personally :)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi The problem is fixed by the latest update.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in 1.0.6 since it was related to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196968/unable-to-read-rendered-markdown-due-to-black-box?lq=1).